# Can I show fragments of research articles in an educational video?

Tags: authorship, legal-issues

I'm considering making a public educational video about finding information using search engines like Pubmed. I consider filming the whole process with searching, reading and analyzing the abstract and then getting into details in the full article.

I'm wondering if I can legally show fragments of articles in a video. Also, does it depend if the article is open access or not? Can I show anything from behind the paywall?

Or more generally - how much can I legally show for educational purposes in a video without violating any laws?

Comment: The legal question is probably off-topic here, and already the issue of what laws apply seems complicated and require more detail from you. I'm rather confident though that there is no practical risk of getting into trouble with this; and I am certain that this is ethical behaviour.

Comment: @Arno..."no practical risk"... Well, don't show fragments of anything that Disney has under copyright, or any musician. Copyright law still applies, though it varies.

Comment: As a strictly legal question, we can't answer it here  as it is off topic as @Arno, says. But note that the question is more complex than it might appear. Copyright law is normally civil, not criminal, law, and there are various _limited_ exceptions for education and for criticism. You are probably safe enough, though, if you observe the normal limitations that you would in writing a scholarly article. Make the citations clear and don't quote (i.e. show) too much are the main rules. But, lawyers can be a nasty bunch. One rule involves whether what you do affects the value of the original.

Comment: Not sure about PubMed, but WebOfScience has uploaded videos to YouTube on how to search. Haven't watched them, but you may be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Legal questions are beyond the scope of this site, and if you want to be certain then you should seek advice from a lawyer in your jurisdiction (or perhaps from a librarian; those guys know plenty about copyright law).  If you are working at or with a university, you can seek advice from the university legal counsel.

You do not say where you are, so that is the first issue --- the rules applying to you depend on your legal jurisdiction.  Copyright laws differ across jurisdictions, but they generally have rules for "fair use" that can include educational purposes under certain conditions.  If you can't find someone to help you, and you would like to research your own answer to your question, you should consult the relevant copyright laws in your jurisdiction and the requirements for "fair use".